# How do I remove the highlight on the previously selected videos in playlist?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, playlist

I created a video playlist in HTML, and the videos play, but when you select another video, the previous one stays highlighted, and I want the highlight to be removed once another video name is clicked. http://www.evamagnus.com/OurServices.php
In the video.js code, I have

```
var position = 0;
var playlist;
var video;

window.onload = function() {
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    addClickHandlers();
    video.src = "video/" + getFormatExtension();
    video.load();
    video.play();
}

function addClickHandlers() {
    var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("ul#videolist li");
    for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
        var li = liElements[i];
        li.onclick = handleVideoSelection;
    }
}

function handleVideoSelection(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var li = e.target;
    var src = li.getAttribute("data-src");
    var isSelected = li.getAttribute("class");
    if (isSelected == "selected") {
        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
        }
        else if (video.ended) {
            video.load();
            video.play();
        }
        else {
            video.pause();
        }
    }
    else {
        li.setAttribute("class", "selected");
        video.src = src + getFormatExtension();
        video.load();
        video.play();
    }
}

function getFormatExtension() {
    if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4") != "") {
        return ".mp4";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/ogg") != "") {
        return ".ogg";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/webm") != "") {
        return ".webm";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using jQuery you should be able to replace all your code in your video.js file with this...

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var ext = getFormatExtension();  // only need to get the extension once

$("ul#videolist li").click(function(e){
    video.src = e.target.getAttribute("data-src") + ext;
    video.load();
    video.play();

    // 1 - clear them all
    $("ul#videolist li").removeClass();

    // 2 - set the clicked one
    e.target.setAttribute("class", "selected");
});

function getFormatExtension() {
    if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4") != "") {
        return ".mp4";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/ogg") != "") {
        return ".ogg";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/webm") != "") {
        return ".webm";
    }
}
```

here is an online example with a couple css enhancements that help show they are buttons with pointer cursor and hover bg.  added button borders and gradient css styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/AQYjY/8/

hope this works for you (be sure to mark the question as answered)

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm not the dentist. Actually, the videos don't play now.

Comment: They still don't play. I'll have to look into it some more. Thanks.

Comment: They play on my local server, but not on the server where evamagnus.com resides.  I need to make some changes on that server, and will post the outcome.

Comment: Hi DaveAlger:  I apologize for the confusion about the videos not playing.  Originally, I had the site on my local server, then I uploaded it to a different server in order to ask my question, so that others could see it.  The reason why the videos weren't playing is because that server did not have an .htaccess file to allow the video formats to be played.  After the .htaccess file was uploaded, they played.  You did answer my original question about removing the highlight on previously selected videos.  Thank you!!!

Comment: try out these changes to see if it helps get it working for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/AQYjY/8/

Comment: Hi DaveAlger:  I had the same code as yours in JSFIDDLE, but the menu items were not selecting with the bright blue.  The solution was moving the jQuery library to the head section of my HTML, instead of toward the bottom of the body section.  Wow, that took way too long to figure out.  Thanks for your help.